# How to check in gridview that it contains any string or not from vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, gridview

I have one gridview. Can I check any how that In one column if it contains any string or number. and If it contains any string than I want to do some funtion

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please add more details to it.

Comment: Here's a starting block... [IsNumeric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.information.isnumeric?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 0):

Create a loop that goes through each item in that column, and pass that value as `strValue` to this handler:

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(strValue) = False Then
    ' Do something if it contains something
 end if
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=netframework-4.7.2